# get clicked date in bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: events, bootstrap-datepicker

I try to get the date clicked in the bootstrap-datepicker. This is the code so far, I retrieve the date that is selected and not the date that is clicked. What do I need to change to get the clicked date?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var disableDates = ["1-3-2022", "3-3-2022"];
    $('#calendar').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        language: "sv",
        beforeShowDay: function(date){
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if(disableDates.indexOf(dmy) != -1){
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        },
        dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
            alert("Day Clicked");
        },
        eventClick: function (event) {
            alert('event');
        }
    });

$("#calendar .datepicker-days").on('click', 'td.day', function () {
        let selecteddate = $("#calendar").data('datepicker').getFormattedDate('yyyy-mm-dd');
    alert('day clicked ' + selecteddate);
});
</script>
```

Comment: _"I retrieve the date that is selected and not the date that is clicked"_ - the difference being ...? Are you trying to interfere _before_ the date selection happens, or what is the point of this?

Comment: Try and read the `data-date` property of the clicked `td.day` itself, that contains the unix timestamp (in milliseconds, as usual in JS.)

Comment: @cbroe The difference is that the clicked date occurs before the selected date.